# Misleading function notation

Tags: functions

If we want to graph $f(x)=2x-4$ and $g(x) = x^2$ on the same coordinate axis you would normally see $y=2x-4$ and $y=x^2$ written. However in the case of one graph we write $y=f(x)$ to mean $y$ is the value of $f$ at the point $x$. What do we do in the case of two or more graphs? We can't write $y=f(x)=g(x)$ (Why do we use this 'incorrect' notation so often then?), as this only holds when $f=g$ and it's clear $f$ and $g$ can be different functions. Is it better to write $y_1$ and $y_2$?

Comment: We don't write $y = f(x) = g(x)$. And when we write "plot $y = f(x)$" - this expression has its own meaning, different from say "lets fix $x, y$ such that $y = f(x)$".

Comment: Let me rephrase. How many times have you seen $y=g(x)$ and $y=f(x)$ being written together? How do we assign two functions to the same variable.

Comment: Let me emphasize: don't write them together.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand. There is plenty of examples, e.g "plot $y=5x$ and $y=x^2$ on the same coordinate axis".

Comment: Why does that confuse you? They want us to plot two *different* functions. If you insist that it is confusing notation because you take the two $y$'s to be litterally the same you overthink this by far. There are probably more ways to confuse someone by notation than to find clear notation. Notation is not bullet proof. Reading it requires human judgement.

Comment: I think he misunderstood your first comment (as I also have trouble to understand it, especially the "together"). @KurtG.

Comment: Both longer form answers I've received definitely write them together.

Comment: My question to OP is: Let's say you wanted to compare what two different curves (including straight lines) look like. How would *you* do this?

Comment: I would just write $y=f(x)$ and $y= g(x)$ then plot them. Like I always have, just because I can do something doesn't mean it's not slightly confusing, but it's all good now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we write $y=2x-4$, that is the name of a certain straight-line-shaped collection of points in the plane (or rather one of its many names). Writing $y=f(x)$ is entirely synonymous.

When we write $y=x^2$, that is the name of a certain parabola-shaped collection of points in the plane (or rather one of its many names). Writing $y=g(x)$ is entirely synonymous.

Drawing both of these sets in the same coordinate system and labelling one of them as $y=2x-4$ and the other as $y=x^2$ is entirely unproblematic. Those are simply the full names of the graphs. There is no double-role of $y$ here. It always refers to the second coordinate of an arbitrary point in the plane. Each graph is defined as the set of points where the relevant relation between $x$ and $y$ coordinates is satisfied.

Using $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ in the right-hand sides does not change this.

Comment: Is this analogy correct: If given some input $x$ we put it into both $f$ and $g$ to return two values of $y$ which we can then plot? Then do this for all $x$ and we have the plots of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

Comment: @nav That is another way of thinking about it, yes. "If you want the graph of $f$, then you get the $y$-coordinate of any point by inserting the $x$-coordinate into $2x-4$" is an entirely reasonable interpretation. It gets you into slight issues with more complicated expressions, like the circle $x^2+y^2=1$, but for now it's good enough.

Comment: Everything in the form $f(x,y) = k$ is just, "All the points $(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y) = k$.

Comment: @nav Exactly. And we can do that with your examples too: $2x-y=4$ and $x^2-y=0$

Comment: If we have $y=f(x)$, $y=g(x)$ and $f(1) ≠ g(1)$ and substitute $x=1$, we get $y= g(1) = g(1)$ but this is obviously not true. Does that mean the two $y$ have different meanings.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a legend or a conveniently placed label relatively to the curves there is no problem with using the same name $y$ for multiple functions on a plot.

In $f(x)=y$ and $g(x)=y$, the $x$ and $y$ names denotes the same objects, namely the coordinates on the plane. But depending on the function it leads to different graphs. Indeed a graph is not an equation but a set defined by an equation. By naming the curve after the equation you are making a shortcut but there is no problem with that as writing $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2, f(x)=y \}$ does not bring any useful information.

Comment: No one likes my answer :(

Comment: It's fine. I understand now. $y$ is not a fixed thing but rather a name for a point that goes in the second space of the coordinate $(a,b)$